# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, java-ee-6

I have a maven dependency for javaee Bibliothek.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get the error in Eclipse in some classes.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException
```

I added javax.mail dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It did not not work.  Any Idea??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It did not work because classes from `javax/javaee-api/provided` dependency are specially constructed. They are not usable runtime because implementation of methods is missing.

Simply adding classes from `javax.mail/mail/1.4.5` dependency to the classpath does not help, because classes from `javax/javaee-api/provided` are already there. Having `javax.mail/mail/1.4.5` dependecy alone solves your problem, but most likely you also need other classes from `javax/javaee-api/provided`.

What you can do is to get rid of `javax/javaee-api/provided` dependency and get these classes for example from the dependencies provided by target application server. You can use for example following:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
```

Because scope is provided, it does not affect the artifact to be built. That's why you can use this one also with other application servers than JBoss. It is same API as in your original dependency, but it contains *normal* classes.

Comment: I added more instructions to answer.

Comment: I always put the javaee-api dependency LAST in the pom.xml, with the implementation jars before it, that fixes it too

Answer (score 6):

Weird but the following order works for me,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The reverse won't work.

Comment: This Actually works. @prayag upd Can you please post little more details about how it works exactly.

Comment: This works for me. The explaination IMHO is the following: Order is worth in class path. So, this way the compiler uses the javax.mail.MessagingException class contained in the first package, instead of the second one.

Answer (score 4):

in my case, only use the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Run with JDK 6 and Tomcat without problems

Comment: I need also the other libraries from javaee

Answer (score 0):

If you add them to your pom in this order:
javax.mail
javaee-web-api
it is pretty logical that it will work, because the runtime finds the necessary class first (with the proper implementation) from javax.mail, ignoring any similar class (without implementation) from javaee-web-api.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use following order. Work very well with JDK6.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javaee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```