# java.lang.ClassFormatError: when trying to mock HttpServletRequest using Mockito

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I am running some unit tests within Eclipse and I am using Mockito to mock as follows:-

```
    HttpServletRequest mockRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

When I run the test from **within Eclipse** I get the following stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
```

However I do not receive any such errors when run from the command line using maven

I have seen similar questions posted elsewhere and I have made sure I have the implementation jars and not just the API jars. My maven dependency is as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>10.0-b28</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have spent way too much time on this, fiddling with my classpaths and cleaning my workspace multiple times but to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142872/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o <-- have you had a look here?

Answer (score -1):

I just created a simple test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    System.out.println(request);
}
```

with my Helios eclipse and with dependency provided by you - everything works as expected, no exceptions.... You might have something else on your classpath in eclipse or the problem might come from a different line.

You can try checking which jar is used using (for example)

```
HttpServletRequest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
```

You could also consider using httpunit instead of mocking request.