# NoSuchMethodError: MultivaluedMap.addAll in Jersey Client

Tags: java, jersey, client, jax-rs

I'm trying to use Jersey Client to simulate HTTP requests to my web service. I tried to implement the [simple example](http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e2365) from the documentation. Here's my short code:

```
public void restoreTest(String sessionId) throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target(idsUrl).path("restore");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("sessionId", sessionId);
    target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
}
```

I didn't even implement the whole example, because currently I get an exception in the last line:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:60)
    at org.icatproject.idsclient.TestingClient.restoreTest(TestingClient.java:112)
    at org.icatproject.ids.ids2.ArchiveTest.restoreThenArchiveDataset(ArchiveTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I only added this dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to google the problem, as well as debug the application, but I can't really see what's wrong with it.

**EDIT**

All Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your pom dependencies?

Comment: @orid Added the dependencies.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This looks like an inconsistency pertaining to the JAX-RS API version (which contains the MultiValuedMap).

You are using client jersey-client v2.2, which is compiled against v2.0 of the JAX-RS API. But your runtime states to run with Java EE 6, which defines JAX-RS API v1.1. So your code expects v2.0 of the JAX-RS API, but gets v1.1 at runtime.

This is the MultiValuedMap API for Java EE 6:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html (no addAll method).

And for Java EE 7:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html (this one includes the addAll method).

As you are using Java EE 6, you should be using jersey-client v1.8, not 2.2. Or you should be including the Java EE 7 API in your runtime classpath, and not 6.

Comment: Thank you! It has to work on Glassfish3, so I decided to keep to JEE6 and use `jersey-client` 1.8. One more thing that was wrong with my dependencies was the `provided` scope of `javaee-api`. Jersey Client needs concrete implementation of it if it is to work outside the server (e.g. during integration tests). This helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142872/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o

Comment: Mixing jersey-client 1.8 and 2.x could cause such issue. After cleaning up the dependencies and only using jersery-client 2.x, the same problem is gone in my application

Comment: I thought I removed all jersey 1.x dependencies but found that I still had `javax.ws.rs.jsr311-api` version 1.1.1 in my dependencies. After removing it the problem was gone...

Comment: For mvn, run `mvn dependency tree` and for gradle, run `gradle dependencies` and survey the list of dependencies to identify potential conflicts.

Comment: @Alexander Bollaert : How can you identify the runtime version ?

Comment: If you're running on a J2EE certified server, the specification version pegs the component API versions. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition (Web Profile).

Answer (score 8):

The offending class comes from this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It has jax-rs 1.1 core classes inside, specifically `MultivaluedMap` interface without `addAll` method.

Either disable it (It seems you can if only using Jersey), or upgrade to `version` to `7.0`

Comment: Ori Dar: how did/would you exactly disable the jax-rs 1.1 from the dependency? I tried excluding artifactId core from group javax.ws.rs, also jsr311-api from same group as separate try and once I had even javaee-api dependency set to 7.0. Neither case, no one has helped alone. Should some combo or different exclusion to be used?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this looks to be an incompatibility issue with Jersey Client and Jersey Core. I got past it by disabling the client:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
            <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.19</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sauce_junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```