# Jersey and Maven results in java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jersey

I just starting to use Maven and wanted to change my current JavaFX8 FXML application to work with Maven. As a test, I'm trying to retrieve a list of countries from my webservice running on Glassfish 3.

When I run the program, this happens in my FXML controller at `initialize()`:

```
CountryClientSSL cc = new CountryClientSSL();
cc.setUsernamePassword("username", "password");
ObservableList<Country> olCountries = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cc.findAll());

olCountries.stream().forEach((country) -> {
    System.out.println(country.getName());
});

cc.close();
```

The `findAll()` method:

```
public List<Country> findAll() throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path("countries");
    System.out.println(resource.getUri().toString());
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(new GenericType<List<Country>>(){});
}
```

The URI looks fine and works with the credentials if I test it in my browser, however the following error is being thrown:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:221)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:59)
at DA.CountryClientSSL.findAll(CountryClientSSL.java:85)
...
```

My pom.xml file has the Jersey dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

I found a similar (old) question here [NoSuchMethodError: MultivaluedMap.addAll in Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574145/nosuchmethoderror-multivaluedmap-addall-in-jersey-client) but it didn't help me much further. Could someone point me in the right direction about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Structure

```
src
 |-main
     |-java
          |-classes
          |-DA
          |-GUI (the controllers, still have to rename this)
     |-resources
          |-bundles
          |-fxml
          |-images
          |-jnlp
          |-styles
target
pom.xml
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: nothing special, just the normal Maven structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have a JAX-RS 1.x dependency on your classpath, as described in the question you mentioned: [NoSuchMethodError: MultivaluedMap.addAll in Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574145/nosuchmethoderror-multivaluedmap-addall-in-jersey-client).

You can run mvn `dependency:tree` to print all (transitive) dependencies of your project. Then check if there is some other Jersey or `javax.ws.rs` dependency preceding the ones you really want.

Comment: Thank you, the dependency:tree command helped me much further. It was indeed a JAX-RS 1.x depency that was being used with the Jira Rest Java Client (doh).