# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jax-rs

After a successful build I try to start tomcat in eclipse to deploy the application, but I am getting the error below. Any clue what could be reason?

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.getBounded(RootClassNode.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getBounded(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:421)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.scanRegistry(ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.java:71)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.<init>(ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet.scanResources(ResteasyWadlServlet.java:75)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet.init(ResteasyWadlServlet.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Feb 12, 2016 4:47:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [ResteasyWadlServlet] in web application [/bw] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.getBounded(RootClassNode.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getBounded(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:421)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.scanRegistry(ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.java:71)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.<init>(ResteasyWadlServiceRegistry.java:63)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet.scanResources(ResteasyWadlServlet.java:75)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.wadl.ResteasyWadlServlet.init(ResteasyWadlServlet.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError: MultivaluedMap.addAll in Jersey Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574145/nosuchmethoderror-multivaluedmap-addall-in-jersey-client)